# VS Code - Jupyter notebook doesn't automatically select the default kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have created a simple jupyter notebook in VS Code and selected it to use my default python3 kernel (/usr/local/bin/python3). Everything works great.

Then, I close VS Code and re-open the notebook, it asks me to select the kernel every time.

Is there a way to default the kernel of this notebook to my python3 interpreter?

In case it helps, when I view the notebook json, it has the following in it:

```
        "kernelspec": {
        "name": "python3",
        "display_name": "Python 3.9.6 64-bit"
```

Comment: It looks like VS Code saves this information on the Workspace level.

If I open a workspace and save it, then later the kernel selection is preserved.
Is there a way to preserve it on the notebook level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not available for now, but they think it is a reasonable request, and considering it. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130946).

Answer (score 4):

Two ways

***one:***

You can go into the command **Juptyer: Filter Kernels**

use command to filter out kernals, all kernals follow alphanumeric order. So, u can tick a few
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/10130

two:

ps. Can try, but might not work after a while? idk why, but it works once.

Enforce choices to only 1, then reload vscode windows

```
"jupyter.kernels.filter": [
      {
        "path": "/bin/python3"
      }
    ]
```

Meanwhile you can visually browser all the paths on ur local
Click the text button at the top right corner. <Python 3.x****>

It pops up like below

[image: how to pick path ?]

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a sufficient condition for python kernel auto-detection (at it fails for new, unseen notebooks).

Comment: What it can achieve though, is to reduce the number of choices on the drop-down list after you manually click on the `Select kernel` button. So it deserves half a point I suppose (rounded up:)

Comment: One interesting side-effect of narrowing python kernels choice to just one (which requires filtering all choice except one) is that python files (`*.py`)  debugger (from the "Debug Python Files" menu) now has no choice other than the correct one, so it works out-of-the box, without additional hacking required.

Answer (score 2):

This option is available in the VS Code settings:

Open settings, search `interpreter` and you should get the option to set an option to set **Python: Default Interpreter Path**

Add the path to the default Python kernel you want to use and Jupyter Labs should always use this specified kernel moving forward.

[image: Default Interpreter Setting]

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a sufficient condition for python kernel auto-detection (at it fails for new, unseen notebooks).

Comment: yep, doesn't work for me. It helps with .py files, but nothing appears in available jupyter kernels